# What is the original source of the TD Advantage Actor-Critic algorithm?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, actor-critic-methods, advantage-actor-critic

What is the original source of the TD Advantage Actor-Critic algorithm?

I found [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@asteinbach/actor-critic-using-deep-rl-continuous-mountain-car-in-tensorflow-4c1fb2110f7c) really helpful for learning the algorithm. However, what is the original source of this algorithm?

[image]